# Trying to get Expiry date from tables in SQL

Tags: t-sql, view

We have a Issuing  Database , where permits are issued. There are 16 tables with row 'EXPIRY' which is datetime. I trying to create TSQL / View which can be queried from all the 16 tables with permits expiring in current month or within 30 days which can be put in excel , as each user has email address, hence the travel office can email the users as forewarning.

```
SELECT dbo.Table1.EXPIRY ,dbo.Table2.EXPIRY AS Expr1 ,dbo.Table3.EXPIRY AS Expr2 ,dbo.Table4.EXPIRY AS Expr3 ,dbo.Table5.EXPIRY AS Expr4 
FROM dbo.Table1 
INNER JOIN dbo.Table2 ON dbo.Table1.ID = dbo.Table2.ID 
INNER JOIN dbo.Table3 ON dbo.Table1.ID = dbo.Table3.ID 
INNER JOIN dbo.Table4 ON dbo.Table1.ID = dbo.Table4.ID 
INNER JOIN dbo.Table5 ON dbo.Table1.ID = dbo.Table5.ID
```

I am Junior DBA, hence just learning TSQL. I was wondering if any one can help

Comment: Give some sample data and what you have tried already.

Comment: Thanks. Please find below as requested
SELECT dbo.Table1.EXPIRY
 ,dbo.Table2.EXPIRY AS Expr1
 ,dbo.Table3.EXPIRY AS Expr2
 ,dbo.Table4.EXPIRY AS Expr3
 ,dbo.Table5.EXPIRY AS Expr4
 
FROM dbo.Table1
INNER JOIN dbo.Table2 ON dbo.Table1.ID = dbo.Table2.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.Table3 ON dbo.Table1.ID = dbo.Table3.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.Table4 ON dbo.Table1.ID = dbo.Table4.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.Table5 ON dbo.Table1.ID = dbo.Table5.ID

Comment: @user16599922 Do your tables have EXPIRY  column ? And please add some sample data for the tables.  Then anyone can have a look. Better if you can add SQL statements. Not just images of tables of data

Answer (score 0):

What you need first is to find all the Tables which have an expiry field,  so you should look them up in the system Tables. Then dynamicly form your querys and execute them.

```
declare @sql varchar(max);

select @sql = CONCAT(@sql, 'select email from dbo.', t.Name, `;`) 
from sys.columns c 
join sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id  
where c.name like 'EXPIRY%'

exec(@sql)
```

Right now this sql would give you x Results, depending on how many tables you have with expiry, you will need to apply the filters and if you want to use a view union all inside the `CONCAT`

Comment: Thanks , It gives me the email addresses , all I need expiry date time from Expiry row . Will try.
Many thanks